# C++ Adding entries to a STL map with a string and a Class instance as a pointer

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, insert

Hello this is my first time using a STL map and im wondering how i can add a new entry to the map.

Here is my code:

```
map<string, Account *> accounts;
string key = "blah";

accounts[key] = Acc;

error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
```

Am i supposed to be using the .insert() function or is this approach the same?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes is is sorry

Comment: So where is `Acc` declared and initialized?

Comment: What is `Acc`?  We can't hellp you without all the details.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need whatsoever for the `*` after Acc. The compiler already knows it is a pointer, since you declared it as one.

```
map<string, Account *> accounts;
Account* Acc = ...;
string key = "blah";
accounts[key] = Acc; // Fine
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i implemented that code but i still got the following error.

task3main.cpp:73: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
task3main.cpp:73: error: cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘Account*’ in initialization

at this line Account* Acc(BSBt,accountt,namet,addresst,phonet,openDatet,balancet);

Comment: any ideas on how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following

```
Account* Acc;
Acc = new Account(args);
```